# Program that compares two files

Tags: diff

Let's say I have two files.. I want to compare them side-by-side and see what's added... anyone know?

Essentially they are the SAME file.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What language? What have you tried? Or are you asking for a program that's already made? If so, this is the wrong place to ask. Try [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: I guess he's looking for diff

Comment: Java files specifically.

Comment: I hate advertising commercial software, but [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is really what you need.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)

Answer (score 3):

fc(file compare) in DOS?

Answer (score 2):

Use diff on linux/unix or windiff on windows.

Answer (score 1):

[DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) from SourceGear is also a nice tool, and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for any *nix based system there is one built in called 'diff' as Raoul mentioned ... there is also 'compare' in the Windows command line which will do essentially the same (but not as thorough) ...

Otherwise you are going to need to be a bit more specific about what you want.